# A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI error

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload

I have a WCF service which was working fine, i recently tried to add code to include an upload file piece and since then i've been getting the following error:
A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

I'm not sure what is going wrong, if i remove the entries i included for the FileUpload part of the service from my config files the site works, but the upload piece won't.  below are my service and client config, can someone look at them and let me know if they see something off:

client Web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRequestType" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRecipientType" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICase" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHoliday" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IManagerType" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDonor" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUser" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICaseStatus" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICaseDonor" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAbsence" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAgency" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocument" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
      openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:01:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRequestType"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IRequestType" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRecipientType"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IRecipientType" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICase"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.ICase" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHoliday"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IHoliday" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IManagerType"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IManagerType" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDonor"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IDonor" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUser"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IUser" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICaseStatus"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.ICaseStatus" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICaseDonor"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.ICaseDonor" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAbsence"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IAbsence" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAgency"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IAgency" name="" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx/DSLDService/DSLDService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocument"
    contract="DSLDServiceReference.IDocument" name="" />
</client>
```

the wcf service web.config looks like:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <!-- set to 2GB files (Maximum allowed per MSDN Documentation) -->
    <binding name="TransferService"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="DSLDService.DSLDService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IRequestType" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IRecipientType" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.ICase" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IHoliday" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IManagerType" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IDonor" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IUser" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.ICaseStatus" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.ICaseDonor" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IAbsence" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="DSLDService.IAgency" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransferService" 
      contract="DSLDService.IDocument" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The problem seems to be with the IDocument class entries, others work ok.  All are BasicHTTPBinding so i thought i could leave them in the same service, not sure why it's telling me a binding is already associated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need all these endpoints and bindings. There should be 1 endpoint and 1 binding in my opinion. I have never seen this configuration before.

Comment: i was building a different Interface for different functionality, i thought i needed endpoints for each interface. for example IUser handles user functionality, while ICase handles functionality related to Cases. Do i not need to do that, can have one endpoint and binding but keep all those interfaces?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you need 1 service, 1 binding, 1 endpoint. And the service contains a bunch of functions like "User" functions, "Case" functions. Binding is an address. In your case I think there should be 1 service, 1 binding, 1 endpoint that has 10-20 functions that the service contains. Keep it simple.

Comment: thank you, i'll look at it and see if i can combine them. after messing with it i realized the problem in my WCF service's config. I had bindingConfiguration="" for all except the IDocument one, so i guess i need to either have that separate in another endpoint, or if i change them all to bindingConfiguration="TransferService" the system works again.